# Make the menu module to not appear in top nav links

Tags: joomla-3.4

I'm new to Joomla CMS and i've kinda run into an issue that is delaying me to launch my website. I have unassigned the menu module to only appear on the main navigation menu. I've selected "only on the selected pages".

Basically, i'm trying to make the main navigation menu to not appear in the top-nav links. 
I'm using a gantry 5 powered theme. Please find the URL here:-  http://marketplace.dateahome.co.uk

Kindly assist me on this,
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using gantry powered theme.

In gantry powered theme the main navigation menu may belong to navigation section under gantry template and not from menu module in this case menu assignment under your module won't work.

What you can do is:

1. go to joomla template manager duplicate your template and open the
   new (duplicate) template.
2. List item Click on settings tab and disabled the menu.
3. Now go to assignment tab and assign this template to those menu items you don't want with main navigation.

Comment: I followed your advice and it worked like a spell.                                          I have to thank you as you have saved me from this agony as to why the module assignment is not working.                                               The website is a multi-site and will soon have to accommodate more languages, is there a work-around to achieve the same result? Thank you

Comment: Be sure to mark @Lokendra Joshi's answe as accepted if it has solved your issue.